# Insert images with Media

Tags: 7, nodes, media, wysiwyg

I am using [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) and [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wyswyg) with CKEditor to insert images in the post editing field, and for some reasons I keep getting this code instead of my images.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```js
[[
  {
   "type" : "media",
    "view_mode" : "media_large",
    "fid" : "412",
    "attributes" : {
      "alt" : "",
      "class" : "media-image",
      "typeof" : "foaf:Image"
    }
  }
]]

[[
  {
    "type" : "media",
    "view_mode" : "media_large",
    "fid" : "395",
    "attributes" : {
      "alt" : "",
      "class" : "media-image",
      "typeof" : "foaf:Image"
    }
  }
]]
```

I fixed it; you have to go into Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats and check the box Converts Media tags to Markup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it; you have to go into Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats and check the box Converts Media tags to Markup.

Comment: This is what should be in Drupal instead of that error message

Comment: This isn't solving the problem for me.

Comment: I have the same problem and checked the "Convert Media tags to markup" option, but the image (in my case) is not shown (I have the problem when creating a tcpdf file).